# Pumping triangles

Tags: mathematics, geometry

On the inside of the triangle (0,0),(1,0),(0,1), define the *"pretty useless map"* or *pump* by the following prescription:

[image]

Given a point *A* find its projections *x*0,*y*0 to the *x* and *y* axes and also *x*1,*y*1 to the same axes shifted by one unit. Connect *x*1 to *y*0 and *y*1 to *x*0. The intersection of these two straight lines shall be *pump*(*A*)

Question:

> Given a triangle *ABC* show that the area of triangle *pump*(*A*)*pump*(*B*)*pump*(*C*) can be written as *f*(*X*) for some fixed scalar function *f* where *X* is the area of *ABC*.

Most elegant solution wins.

Hint 1:

> A purely geometric, zero algebra solution exists.

Hint 2 (**Warning: this really is a spoiler**):

> [image]

Source: Me.

Comment: @hexomino Nope, the picture is correct. What may be off is my verbal description. By shifting an axis by one unit I mean, for example, that the equation for the x axis (y=0) becomes y=1 after shifting. So if A=(x,y) then x0 = (x,0), x1 = (x,1).

Comment: Yep, my apologies, I understand now. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The alternative solution:

> First apply a *dual transformation*.  That is, we take the dual of the configuration by replacing each point with a line and each line with a point, as shown.
>  [image: dual]
>  (If you've never heard of this trick and it sounds unbelievably wacky, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(projective_geometry) and scroll down to the Poles and Polars section for a construction of such a transformation.  I got this particular transformation by swapping poles with polars around a small circle whose center lies in the upper-right "quadrant" of the rectangle.)
>  
>  Under this transformation, it suffices to show that the three dark blue (violet?) lines are concurrent.

Then:

> We apply **Pappus's Theorem** on the two thin black lines (these happen to be the duals of two infinity points that were present in the original diagram).
>  Pappus states that if $A,B,C$ lie on a line $L_1$ and $X,Y,Z$ lie on a line $L_2$, then the points $AY \cap BX,BZ \cap CY,AZ \cap CX$ are collinear!  They don't have to lie in any particular order, so we choose this order:
>   [image: pappus]
>   Applying Pappus to the thin black lines and labelling the six points in question in *this specific order*, a direction application of Pappus gets that the three light blue points are collinear.  This is sufficient to show that the three dark blue (violet?) lines are concurrent.

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind. Well done! Btw., apparently it is called Pappus' hexagon theorem in English and the wikipedia article even has [a section on its dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_hexagon_theorem#Dual_theorem). And there is a picture labelled dual theorem: affine form. Note: I only found this after publishing the puzzle. I may be lazy wrt puzzle design (Take famous theorem and obfuscate.) but not *that* lazy.

Comment: You being a bit of a projective geometry expert, do you agree that @Gareth's answer is essentially a proof of Pappus?

Comment: I suppose so.  The original problem was essentially a purely projective one in that it can be obtained from the general case by sending some points to infinity and using the other two degrees of freedom to make the square.  Then solving this specific case will solve the general one via projective transformations, which then leads to Pappus via duality.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a short but rather unenlightening algebraic proof. (I thought I had a nice simple more-geometric proof but it has a hole, so while I think about filling the hole I'll write this one out so there's *a* solution.)

> The function f is the constant function with value zero, because the area is always 0, because all points pump(P) lie on a single fixed line, namely y=x. Proof: if P is at (x,y) the lines we're interested in are -yX+(1-x)Y=-xy and (1-y)X-xY=-xy. The point pump(P) is on their intersection and therefore also satisfies -X+Y=[-yX+(1-x)Y]-[(1-y)X-xY]=(-xy)-(-xy)=0 or X=Y.

Comment: Yes, they should. It occurs to me that there's a geometrical proof that's kinda equivalent to this one, which I'll edit into my answer.

Comment: Duh, no, my kinda-equivalent geometrical proof is not in fact a proof (so I hope it also isn't kinda-equivalent).

Comment: (Something about this problem seems to make my brain come up with a lot of bogus proofs. For about a minute I thought I had it as a trivial consequence of a famous theorem, but I now think that was completely wrong too.)

Comment: All smoke and mirrors. I'm curious. Which theorem?

Comment: The one about the midpoints of the diagonals of a complete quadrilateral.

Comment: I don't want to spoiler it for you so all I'm going to say is you are kind of close.

Comment: Yeah, there's a definite projective-geometry vibe to this. (I take it that's part of what your recent hint is gesturing towards.) In particular, of course the result is unchanged if you apply a projective transformation to the whole picture. And the exact picture in your second hint is one that I've had in my head, though mostly as a _mistake_ because of course it doesn't quite directly match the pumping process. Unfortunately I'm kinda rubbish at projective geometry :-).

Comment: Haha, as someone that's spent quite some time studying projective geometry, I don't quite see it either :p

Usually the proof would go the other way around anyway; starting from the general projective configuration, you easily get the desired collinearity using coordinates after you send four points to a square.

Comment: Yes, I do have my doubts whether the "intended" solution will really be clearly simpler than the (really quite simple) algebraic proof I already have. It may make it more apparent how far the result generalizes, though.

Comment: Actually, I'm getting a bit nervous that I made some basic mistake, seeing as now two formidable maths buffs seem unable to make the intended simple last step. But assuming I didn't, using the principle @greenturtle3141 mentioned Gareth's algebraic argument could I think be made into a nice proof of the thing I seem to have hidden so darn well.

Comment: Indeed it could. I bet you haven't made a mistake; I really meant it when I said I'm bad at projective geometry. I keep looking at it, thinking "this should be a trivial consequence of some standard theorem about projective things", go looking up theorems, think "ah, yes, it's this one", and then realise that the bit of my brain saying that is getting some construction completely wrong.

Comment: Quite fun watching this discussion unfolds, haha. Geometry is one of my weakest subject too, so I don't expect myself to be able to contribute much to this already great answer. Haha. Hopefully someone will see through loopy's trick soon!

Comment: Ok, here is another (potentially useless) hint: Good job that google reverse image search is rubbish at projective geometry, too.

Comment: Hope you don't mind my using your celeb status for advertising this puzzle.

Comment: I'm intrigued. What did you do?

Comment: ... Oh, the bounty. I see. No, no objections to that :-).